# How to bypass a Proxy Server when needed?

Tags: proxy, tcpserver

I setup a **proxy server in my local machine** for a testing purpose, in which I request for a **web page which is constantly being updated via a back end TCP server**. But since the **proxy is caching the web page, it is not being updated properly. Instead I get the cached page**. Is there a way to bypass the proxy server other than adjusting the settings of it???

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question, and are close to [using a chocolate-covered banana](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).  The right question to ask is why your proxy is retaining and passing along stale data.  And the answer to that is very probably that your content HTTP server isn't properly generating `ETag:` or `Last-Modified:` headers or properly responding to back-end validation requests from the proxy HTTP server.  Fix your content HTTP server so that it properly informs the proxy HTTP server whether and when cached data are stale.  There's a whole section of RFC2616, §13, devoted to how caching is handled in the protocol.

Comment: Well, if I knew that, I sure would have asked it, its the first time I worked with a proxy server. We are all in these forums to share our knowledge and to learn what is unknown to us. Thanks for the answer anyway... :)